# Unable to install graylog-web

Tags: package-management, software-installation

```
Package graylog-web is not available, but is referred to by another package.  

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source.
E: Package 'graylog-web' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to notice that **Graylog** has four main components:

1. Graylog Server nodes: Serves as a worker that receives and processes messages, and communicates with all other non-server components.
2. Elasticsearch nodes: a server that stores all of the logs & messages.
3. MongoDB: For storing metadata
4. Web Interface: the GUI

You have to install all the prerequisites first:

Installing Java then update:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Install MongoDB  and create the source list:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

after that update and install the latest available stable version:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Install Graylog Server:

```
cd ~
wget https://packages.graylog2.org/repo/packages/graylog-1.3-repository-ubuntu14.04_latest.deb
sudo dpkg -i graylog-1.3-repository-ubuntu14.04_latest.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get install graylog-server
sudo apt-get install pwgen
SECRET=$(pwgen -s 96 1)
sudo -E sed -i -e 's/password_secret =.*/password_secret = '$SECRET'/' /etc/graylog/server/server.conf
PASSWORD=$(echo -n password | shasum -a 256 | awk '{print $1}')
sudo -E sed -i -e 's/root_password_sha2 =.*/root_password_sha2 = '$PASSWORD'/' /etc/graylog/server/server.conf
```

Until this step the admin password is there installed, after that you need to configure graylog to your needs, and you can find the config file here :

```
sudo vi /etc/graylog/server/server.conf
```

Good luck,